# Adding elliptic curve intermediate to Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to add an existing elliptic curve intermediate CA certificate to Vault using the following

```
vault write pki/config/ca pem_bundle=@bundle.json
```

bundle.json contains

```
{
    "pem_bundle":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\...\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----"
}
```

this gives the error 'no data found in PEM block' - which I believe is because it is expecting an RSA certificate.
Looking at https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/pki

there is a `key_type` parameter that can be set to EC. but this does not appear to be available for `pki/config/ca`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API docs to [submit a CA](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/pki#submit-ca-information) specifically note the following:

> Note that if you provide the data through the HTTP API it must be
> JSON-formatted, with newlines replaced with \n, like so...

This applies only to the HTTP API (eg: `curl ... https://.../v1/pki/config/ca`).

However, you are using the `vault write` CLI command which does the translation from inputs to json format for you. The `pem_bundle` argument to the CLI command should be a path to a plain `.pem` file containing the normal PEM-formatted certificate and key. eg:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
...
...
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Your final invocation will be:

```
vault write pki/config/ca pem_bundle=@ca_bundle.pem
```

Note also that the `key_type` argument is only needed when a key is being generated by Vault. Since you are providing the key, Vault will properly detect the key type (see [certutil.ParsePemBundle](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/sdk/helper/certutil/helpers.go#L119)).

Comment: this worked, thank you. Though I may have had something wrong with formatting etc as I needed to run the private key through openssl before it would accept it. (using -outform pem)